# Microsoft Dynamics 2016 Web API | POST invoicedetail

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016, microsoft-dynamics-webapi

I am able to `POST` and [`invoice EntityType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593070.aspx) to the Web API.

After creating the `invoice` I get the `guid` and I want to create invoice line items, which I believe are of [`invoicedetail EntityType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607742.aspx).

I cannot `POST` a new `invoicedetail`. Every attempt I make with a range of different properties I receive either an `Error 500 - An unexpected error occurred.` or `Error 500 - The parent id is missing.`

An example of a JSON string I'm trying to `POST`. (`invoicedetailid` is the `GUID` of the previous invoice I create)

```
{
    "productdescription": "Test Line Item", 
    "invoicedetailid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000",
    "priceperunit": 10,
    "tax": 0,
    "quantity": 1,
    "baseamount": 10  
}
```

The documentation is vague and I'm wanting to know, what are the minimum  required fields for `invoicedetail` and how can I `POST` a new `invoice EntityType`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field storing to lookup from `invoicedetail` to `invoice` is called `invoiceid` (not `invoicedetailid`, which is the id of the `invoicedetail` itself). Additionally, you need to use the [@odata.bind-annotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328090.aspx#Anchor_3):

> To associate new entities to existing entities when they are created
>   you must set the value of single-valued navigation properties using
>   the @odata.bind annotation.

The body of your POST request would thus look as follows:

```
{
    "productdescription": "Test Line Item", 
    "invoiceid@odata.bind": "/invoices(guid-of-invoice-here)",
    "priceperunit": 10,
    "tax": 0,
    "quantity": 1,
    "baseamount": 10  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Henrik. Works a treat!